# passing fixture as another fixture's decorator params

Tags: pytest

trying to use the pytest's feature to pass params=[] to fixture's decorator expecting it to be invoked individually for each of the passed values. as a param I want to pass another fixtures (just a demo code):

```
import pytest

@pytest.fixture
def rates():
    return (1.12, 1.15, 1.37)

@pytest.fixture
def expires():
    return (102, 105, 107)

@pytest.fixture(params=[rates, expires])
def data(request):
    return request.param

def test_vol(data):
    assert len(data) == 3
```

this just fails complaining with:

```
TypeError: object of type 'function' has no len()
```

is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

one possible solution I just found:

```
@pytest.fixture(params=[rates, expires])
def data(request):
    return request.getfuncargvalue(request.param.__name__)
```

not very straightforward though...